# Best video format for a retired PowerPC (iBook G4)?

Tags: codec, file-formats, mac, osx

We have a retired iBook G4, it plays H.264 quite laggy.

My question is what is the best video format **optimizing for Battery Life** on a PowerPC?

---

Bonus question: Is there a free batch converter for macOS to process 300+ file?

---

Is there a forum somewhere better suited for this kind of question?

Comment: Instead of the “bonus” question it would be better to ask it as another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPEG4 encoded with [**Handbrake**](https://handbrake.fr/), or use Xvid with [**ffmpegX**](https://www.ffmpegx.com/download.html).

[**MacRumors** PowerPC forum](https://forums.macrumors.com/forums/powerpc-macs.145/) is definitely a better place to discuss this.